# RoadMap for WebDevelopment

Tags: asp.net, django, rest

Hi I am a software developer with experience in python and .Net platform. I would like to get advice for Web Development RoadMap. How should I get started what platform should I choose. I would like advice on the following points:

- Which framework should I use?
- Handling of API
- Backend of the application and if SQL or NoSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have already worked with .NET, so I would suggest you go with ASP.NET Core.
I'm also learning Web development and have been working on it for the last 1yr.

This is the path I followed and am still following:

1. Learn front-end(Basic of Web > HTML > CSS > Bootstrap/Bulma/SCSS > JS)
2. Learn FTP, GIT/GitHub, Hosting etc
3. Learn C#(Till Advance)
4. Learn SQL Server/MySQL
5. Learn Entity Framework Core
6. Create some demo apps with DataBase
7. Start Learning ASP.NET Core
8. Learn Blazor/Angular

Comment: for the backend I think I should use MSSQL as it has better integration with C# and .net what are your thoughts @Alcoholic

Comment: SQL Server is most suitable for .NET, but I suggest you to do both, there is not much difference, First, learn SQL Server and then you can easily learn MySQL.

Comment: Sorry for late reply and can i pick your brain for a few moment. Should I also try NoSQL as there is hype in that particular database

Comment: Of course, you should try NoSQL, but for now, I think SQL Server will work fine, once you have a good command on it, you can easily go for NoSQL.
The database is not an issue, first focus on FrontEnd and C#, and once you are confident enough then start learning Database.
Remember that C# is a big, famous, and Interesting language, with .NET you'll work on C# so make sure you spent plenty of time on it.

Comment: Ok thank you very much